# Spring actuator in 2.7 not available get 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

i am trying to get actuator refresh to work and i cant seem to get it to work. I keep getting 404. The application is basic hello world, have not added anything other than a controller which responds with "Hello". That all works.. but i cant seem to get access to the health or info endpoints.. i read these  should be available

my versions are:
Gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.3'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Tried:

Application.properties
server:
port: 9999

```
server:
  port: 9999

management:
  health:
    refresh:
      enabled: true
```

This too:

```
management:
  info:
    env:
      enabled: true
```

i dont think the last one is even available in 2.7

Im using the latest actuator which is 2.7.3, and the url im trying is

http://localhost:9999/actuator/health

Comment: Which URL are you using?  Also the property is `management.endpoint.health.enabled`. Basically the pattern is `management.endpoint.[endpoint-name].enabled` and other related properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum im using the folllwing url http://localhost:9999/actuator/health

Comment: Do your plugins have `io.spring.dependency-management`available?

Comment: Default port is 8080 for Spring boot app, please try using that.

Comment: @fatih yes it does updated question.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh i set it inside the properties to be 9999

Comment: to make endpoints available in browser `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,refresh,... `

Comment: You are using `cloud-config`. Could your actuator configurations from here affect your project? You should also be able to access the /`actuator/health` endpoint without making any additions to your `application.yml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm upgrading our application's spring boot version from 2.6 to 2.7. I had a similar problem, the actuator endpoint did not show up when I changed spring-boot-starter-actuator version from 2.6.11 to any 2.7.* version.

But when I added spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure dependency manually, the actuator started to work as before.

So try to add *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure* to your to dependencies.

I cant figure out why this solves the problem. It should work without adding this dependency manually. Maybe the changes in the spring autoconfiguration somehow affected the actuator auto configuration.

Comment: Not working for me, even if I added manually spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure.

Comment: also not working for me that's not the solution

Answer (score 1):

spring-boot-starter-actuator version 2.7.11 with autoconfigure version 2.5.12 works

[Dependency graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbHeN.png)