# Spring actuator not available after update spring boot version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, actuator

Spring actuator not available after update spring boot version

[2023-09-06T13:31:30.830Z] WARNNING: https://fe-name.dev.company.io/actuator/health is not reachable! hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 6

IN the spring application I see this line:

```
2023-09-06 13:31:08.105  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

which means it should be up and working

having these dependencies and others

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> <!--for health check-->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.15</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>



  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Maybe spring changed actuator health check endpoint ?

I tried also this solution but it didn't help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625630/spring-actuator-in-2-7-not-available-get-404)

Comment: If you are using the Maven Shade plugin, then follow the instructions in the release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes

Comment: Does anything appear under /actuator or is only /actuator/health affected?